# Deep Linking "OnAppLinkRequestReceived" method is not executed in Xamarin app with LaunchMode = SingleTop

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, deep-linking

I have a Xamarin Forms App for android with `LaunchMode = SingleTop` in **MainActivity.cs**. When the app in invoked for the first time via Deep linking URL, the method  `OnAppLinkRequestReceived` is executed in **App.XAML.cs** file.
In this method I'm setting some app parameters received from URL.

Once I open the app and push it to background using Home button and call the URL again, the app which is running in the background is made active, but  the method `OnAppLinkRequestReceived` is not executed at all. So, I was not able to change the app parameters.

When I kill the app and open the URL again, a new instance of the app is created and `OnAppLinkRequestReceived` is executed.

Is there any way to invoke `OnAppLinkRequestReceived` each time the app URL is called, irrespective of whether the app is already running or not ?

Comment: Looks like you can't open two connections to the URL.  You would need to check if process/connection already exists before calling 2nd time.

Comment: I'm able to open the app each time I call it using URL. 
The problem is that the method `OnAppLinkRequestReceived` is supposed to be executed if the app receives a URL request each time. But, in my case, the method is called only when the app is opened for first time.

Comment: Is OnAppLinkRequestReceived a listener?  Listeners can accept multiple connections from clients and do not need to be create for each client provided the same port number is used.

Comment: This is not exactly a listener, please check link -  

[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.onapplinkrequestreceived?view=xamarin-forms)

There's no scope for port numbers as we are talking about android mobile app.

Comment: See following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/deep-linking?force_isolation=true#indexing-a-page  Since you have more than one instance you need indexing.

Comment: thank you , I'll refer to the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `OnNewIntent` in MainActivity.cs is blank earlier. I added a call to the base method.

Now, when I try to reopen the app from background, the method `OnAppLinkRequestReceived` is executed.

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
 {
     // Added this line
     base.OnNewIntent(intent);
 }
```